# How to substring value in XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Can anyone please help in wring XSLT for this, I want to substring value of one attribute "UDF/@Value" to first 20 characters and **I want to substring all UDF/@Value** .

Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <Header FileDate="02/12/2015" InputDateFormat="MM/dd/yyyy"/>
  <Body DataType="Account">
<Account  Name="XYZ"  InceptionDate="03/01/2005"  DEPT="USD BU" BusinessUnit="WTC" ClientAccountId="123" ISOCurrency="USD" >
<UDF Name="Product" Value="DUMMY"/>
<UDF Name="QUANTITY" Value="abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwz yz"/>
</Account>
<Account  Name="ABC"  InceptionDate="03/01/2005"  DEPT="USD BU" BusinessUnit="WTC" ClientAccountId="124" ISOCurrency="USD" >
<UDF Name="Comment" Value="abc 10percent and 20 and at xyz"/>
<UDF Name="Product Code" Value="EMMKTOPP"/>
</Account>
</Body>
  <Trailer RecordCount="2"/>
</root>
```

Output xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <Header FileDate="02/12/2015" InputDateFormat="MM/dd/yyyy"/>
  <Body DataType="Account">
<Account  Name="XYZ"  InceptionDate="03/01/2005"  DEPT="USD BU" BusinessUnit="WTC" ClientAccountId="123" ISOCurrency="USD" >
<UDF Name="Product" Value="DUMMY"/>
<UDF Name="QUANTITY" Value="abc def ghi jkl mno "/>
</Account>
<Account  Name="ABC"  InceptionDate="03/01/2005"  DEPT="USD BU" BusinessUnit="WTC" ClientAccountId="124" ISOCurrency="USD" >
<UDF Name="Comment" Value="abc 10percent and 20"/>
<UDF Name="Product Code" Value="EMMKTOPP"/>
</Account>
</Body>
  <Trailer RecordCount="2"/>
</root>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to substring *all* UDF/@Value“?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an identity template to copy all nodes:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

And a specific template to deal with the `UDF` element, applying substring only on the `Value` attribute:

```
<xsl:template match="UDF">
    <UDF Value="{substring(@Value, 0, 20)}" Name="{@Name}"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot helderdarocha